# Android networkonmainthreadexception from non main thread

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

I am working on an android app which involves connecting to a server. I've been getting networkonmainthreadexceptions, even when creating a socket in a new thread (and using an Async Task).
The socket works fine from a normal java program, the IP is on the local network, and pinging works fine.
Phone is nexus galaxy, android version 4.0.2

```
package uk.ac.cam.echo.app;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;


public class DBTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("192.168.15.98",44444);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `doInBackground`? Sounds like you're still calling it from the main application thread. e.g. `task = new DBTask(); task.doInBackground();`.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging out `android.os.Process.myTid()` from the place where your AsyncTask is called and from inside `doInBackground`.  If they're the same, then your AsyncTask isn't actually moving into the threadpool.

Can you supply the code where you activate the AsyncTask as well?

Comment: Fixed. Turns out wifi wasn't fully configured. Still not sure why it was throwing networkonmainthreadexception though...